# Broken dependicie mysql-community-server

Tags: package-management, mysql

I try sudo `apt-get upgrade` but it show this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-client (= 5.7.22-1debian7) but 5.7.32-1debian9 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and if i run this `sudo apt --fix-broken install` it show

```
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-server_5.7.32-1debian9_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-community-server.postinst: line 19: /usr/share/mysql/mysql-helpers: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-community-server_5.7.32-1debian9_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```